# How to publish a zip file in Tridion?

Tags: publishing, 2013-sp1, dynamic-publishing

I have a requirement to publish an html file generated by third party application.

Along with html file, the following files need to uploaded.

- JS
- CSS
- images
- icons
- config/xml files

As a general solution thought of implementing a .NET TBB to publish all the items as multimedia components into custom folders but it requires lot of content authoring for each html file.

Instead I am thinking to upload the complete output folder as ZIP file, which includes all above mentioned items. Unzip the files in presentation server or CD side and create a link to the html file.

How can I publish the zip file using Tridion?

Comment: Doing it this way you will be missing out on the functionality of Tridion, allowing editors to control content.

Comment: Yes, implementing that idea will make Tridion as simple content source and I will miss out the Tridion features, but thought of publishing the HTML file from Tridion (Linking purpose) and pushing all the supported files silently.

Comment: @P.Muralikrishna Tridion is a *Content* Management System and not just a tool for deploying files. Although Tridion's published output is often HTML, this comes from the combination of Content, (Website) Structure and Design. If you do not need to manage the content for your 'generated HTML', then I'd suggest that you look at alternative mechanisms (Continuous Integration / Build Scripts / PowerShell / etc.) for deploying your HTML and accompanying assets.

Comment: As an FYI, Tridion's implementation of WebDAV, at least for DWT files, manages relative references and even converts them to Tridion Content Manager URIs. Take a file and its supporting elements (or save a webpage as "complete"), rename the extension to .dwt, and drag everything into WebDAV. I'm not recommending a single DWT per third-party page, though. :-) This could be an in-between step if you didn't want to go the ZIP route. If ZIP has a mime type, then you should be able to publish it as a Multimedia Component, but you'd lose the "linking purpose" part.

Answer (score 1):

The direct answer to the question is that this is fairly trivial to achieve in Tridion.

You can create a multimedia type for zip files, and use that in a multimedia schema, that in turn will allow you to create and publish a multimedia component.

On the content delivery side, you could implement a custom storage that takes care of extracting the contents to the right locations.

But, as various commenters have noted, just being able to do something, doesn't make it a good idea. I'd suggest you look at the deployment techniques available that fit with your environment and technology choices.

Answer (score 0):

Muralikrishna, like Chris is mentioning in his comment, doing it like you suggesting you miss out on the functionality of Tridion.

If this is not a requirements to have, and no Tridion involvement from the CMS is required why not setup a seperate deployment process outside Tridion for this ?
If Tomcat, create a war file and deploy it inside the Tomcat instance or something similair.

Comment: Thought of using publish/un publish feature of Tridion in case of HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

The Tridion Reference Implementation contains this (or very similar) functionality. Please check it out: http://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/reference_implementation.aspx.